# Deserializing NodaTime Instant from System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nodatime

I'm using Noda Time in an ASP.NET Core project and a model that contains two `Instant` properties.

```cs
public class Template
{
    //... redacted bits

    public Instant CreateDt { get; set; }
    public Instant LastmodDt { get; set; }
}
```

The info in the database is as I expect "out of box." However *getting back* the values via API returns empty object properties like this:

```json
{
    //... redacted bits

    "createDt": {},
    "lastmodDt": {}
}
```

How do I get back the same date I put in, or at least some data I can massage into it?

FWIW I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1, with the default System.Text.Json (not JSON.NET).

**Edit**: Removed spurious notes about PostgreSQL which turned out to be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Have you installed and configured the NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson package? (It's not clear how the database is involved here - I'd expect this to be reproducible without anything to do with the database, at which point your question could be simplified.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You are quite right. I didn't realize that I was looking at a previous version of the NodaTime user guide (from a Google search), and therefore couldn't find any reference to System.Text.Json serialization. Smooth on my part. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: Cool. If you've got it working now, you might want to just add an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with an assist noted in the comments, by installing the `NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson` package and adding this to my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    // the added bit:
    .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
```

I had to reverse-engineer this from other uses found on github since I was looking at the wrong version of the userguide for NodaTime like a doofus. Cheers.